# Asp.Net mvc routes to other site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

Can I declare something like this in RegisterRoutes method:

```
routes.MapRoute() (
    name: "DefaultApi",
    url: "http://localhost:52657/api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new {id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I want access ASP.NET Web API (run in another URL)

Comment: Your question is vague, add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do a URL rewrite.

Either via the URL rewrite module > http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Or by code...

```
public class UrlRewriteModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var app = sender as HttpApplication;

                if ( app == null )
                {
                    return;
                }

                Uri url = app.Request.Url;

                // Allows the CSS file to be cached per Company+Version
                if ( string.Equals(url.ToString(), "http://not/what/I/want", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) )
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/a/better/url");
                    return;
                }
            };
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```